# jquery add function doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following snippet doesn't work.

```
var empty = $();
var divs = $("div");
empty.add(divs);
```

There is a div element in the HTML and it is added correctly to *divs*. But the divs collection is not added to the *empty* jquery object.
Any ideas what`s wrong with that?

Comment: It works as it's [documented](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`.add` won't change the original object. Try:

```
empty = empty.add(divs);
```

Comment: It's right in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/) that it returns a new jQuery collection.

Comment: can you add to an existing set without creating a new one?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
var empty = $.extend($(), $('div'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Jquery doc,

The following will not save the added elements, because the `.add()` method creates a new set and leaves the original set in `pdiv` unchanged:

```
var pdiv = $("p");
pdiv.add("div");  // WRONG, pdiv will not change
```